# How to re-run JavaFX App

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

My main thread launches `javafx.application.Application`, which terminates itslef after its job is finished. When I try to launch the same JavaFX App again, I always receive `IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once.`

Simple demonstrative example:

```
public class MainApp {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      FXApp.setCounter(i);
      System.out.println("launching i="+i);
      FXApp.launch(FXApp.class, args);
    }
  }
}

public class FXApp extends Application {    

  private static int counter;

  public static void setCounter(int counter) {
    FXApp.counter = counter;
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      Platform.exit();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() throws Exception {
    super.stop();
    System.out.println("stopping counter="+counter);
  }

}
```

Console output

```
launching i=0
stopping counter=0
launching i=1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:162)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:143)
  at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:191)
  at ...MainApp.main(MainApp.java:9)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Application` class represents the entire running application. The static method called `launch()` is used to launch the application. Since you can, by definition, only launch any given application once during the lifecycle of the application, it is illegal to call `launch` more than once during the lifecycle of the application, and doing so will throw an exception, as is [clearly and explicitly detailed in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-).

Calling `launch()` creates the instance of the `Application` subclass that represents the running application, starts the JavaFX toolkit, and invokes `start()` on the application instance. Thus the `start()` method is effectively the entry point for the application. Note that `start()` is invoked on the FX Application Thread (so you cannot have long-running or blocking code here). Again, all the details are carefully spelled out in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

You haven't said anything about what you are actually trying to do, and since you are using the methods and classes in ways that are completely opposite to their intended use, it's pretty much impossible to guess what you might mean by this question. However, the equivalent functionality would be achieved with something like

```
public class FXApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Thread pausingAndIteratingThread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    final int counter = i ;
                    Platform.runLater(() -> endIteration(counter));
                }
            }
        };

        pausingAndIterartingThread.start();
    }

    private void endIteration(int counter) {
        System.out.println("stopping: counter="+counter);
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(FXApp.class, args);
    }
}
```